# Looking for OpenSource ASP.NET Project Management

Tags: asp.net, project-management

I found some really good solutions alike : CollabNet (on grails) and others

But when I want to make some changes for my own I really want it being ASP.NET based. Sadly I can't find good solution for it.

Is there open-source project-management systems on asp.net ?

Added : So I'm looking for something that will highlight and browse sources and shows the changes. - that is my main tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [bugnet](http://www.bugnetproject.com/). Though its much of a bug tracker but maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this project. It's good for bug-tracker but seriously I want something where I can see the project and repository changes and files. That is really big work :( and I'm looking for solution because have no time to handle it alone. Temporary solution isn't using ASP.NET )

Answer (score 2):

Here's a listing of mostly all the ASP.net open source projects.
The majority are not really project management though.  There is issue tracking though which can be part of project management:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/388/aspnet-open-source-projects/